# undefined reference to `main' while linking with i386-elf-ld

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, osdev

I followed a tutorial series to program an operating system myself.
But then while trying to cross compile c++ and asm I got this error message:

```
i386-elf-ld: kernel_entry.o:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `main'
i386-elf-ld: /home/teer/Desktop/Programming/C/OperatingSystem/src/boot/kernel_entry.o:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `main'
```

Command used:

```
i386-elf-ld -o "full_kernel.bin" -Ttext 0x1000 "kernel_entry.o" "/home/teer/Schreibtisch/Programming/C/OperatingSystem/src/boot/kernel_entry.o" --oformat binary
```

Kernel C++ file:

```
extern "C" void main(){
    *(char*)0xb8000 = 'Q';
    return;
}
```

Kernel_entry asm file:

```
[bits 32]
[extern main]
call main
jmp $
```

Comment: You listed `kernel_entry.o` twice. One of those should be `kernel.o` (assuming that is your kernel c++ file).

Comment: @Jester That helped but now i'm gettin a warning `warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001000`

Comment: That hardly matters as the binary format doesn't even have a header to store the entry point and in any case nobody would be looking at it.